# How would death by static shock work?

Tags: internal-consistency

Eric von Blowfelt is a evil genius. He has an island with hundreds of minions to make his evil plans into evil action. Unfortunately, 003 (*double-oh three*) has entered the secret base on the island and has taken pictures of Eric's next plan. Blast!

Fortunately, 003 has been captured. Eric wants to kill 003 through static shocks somehow, unfortunately he is fresh out of giant socks to statically charge. How could Eric von Blowfelt generate enough static electricity to give 003 a killing shock?

Comment: How is the shock to be applied? If he can stick a couple hollow tubes with electrodes on the end directly into 003's heart, it won't take much at all. Even stupid things like dumping some salt water onto 003 first can make a huge difference.

Comment: If the accumulated static electricity discharges through poor Mr. Oh-oh Three's body then it is no longer *static*. It really is very simple: *static* electricity does not flow, it is static. By not flowing it cannot produce shocks and, obviously, cannot kill. To give a shock to poor Mr. Oh-oh Three the devious Erik Vaughn Blow-Felt has to allow electricity to flow through the agent's body, thus making an electric current. What Mr. Oh-oh Three feels depends on the intensity and duration of said current, and of course on the affected body parts. But the question as asked is self-contradictory.

Comment: Can static (not flowing) electrical charge actually *kill* someone? I think you need a moving dynamic charge in order to do that.

Comment: @BMF can static electrical charge kill, pedantically, no. But this is the same that a non moving 10 Tonne rock above you can't kill you if it doesn't move.   As soon as the supports of the rock are moved, as soon as the circuit is completed through a body. Bad things happen.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor right, exactly. Makes me wonder what exactly the OP is asking. Is it simply "how to kill someone with electricity?" There are endless ways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eric von Blowfelt needs two things to do in 003: a really large and sinister static charge generator (Van de Graf generator, Kelvin thunderstorm device, or Wimshurst machine, for instance) and an even bigger (and more evil-looking) Leyden jar.  Correctly combined and operated, these two devices can generate and store a charge of hundreds of thousands of volts (the generator itself, however, can only produce milliamps of current at that voltage), and the Leyden jar is a very lethal device which can discharge thousands of amps at tens of thousands of volts.

The result, from 003's perspective, will be much like being struck by lightning: severe burns along the current path, traumatic neural damage, and, of course, cardiac fibrillation -- if von Blowfelt is particularly sadistic, he might well restart 003's heart several times and repeat the treatment, after appropriately dramatic monologues, to give 003 more chances to escape the machine and somehow, still functional after shocks that should have killed any three spies, manage to defeat Blowfelt's plan and drop him down a tall smokestack.

Comment: So, basically, store a bunch of electricity *statically* in a battery, and then discharge it?

Comment: A Leyden jar isn't a battery, it's a condenser (aka capacitor) that dates back to the days when the Van de Graf, Wimshurst, and Kelvin machines were invented.  17th to 18th century, before electric current machines were a thing.  Static is all about voltage, positive and negative charges and their attractive and repulsive forces, and Leyden jars are right in the middle of all of that.

Answer (score 0):

***Volcanic lightning***

I'm pretty sure pictures will be copyrighted, so I won't add some here. But a picture search will give you awesome pictures of smoke and lightning. What better for your evil genius? An evil island is ok. But an evil lair located in an active volcano that has the circumstances to produce Volcanic Lightning with an eruption is just too much cool not to use for static shock killing of your arch enemy.

To make it extra clear. A volcano eruption can cause a plume of ash to arise. This can interact with itself, getting a static charge. This can then be released to itself or the surrounding area. This is also called a *dirty thunderstorm*.

Comment: Lightning kills by pouring a very large electric current through the unfortunate person. Electric current is very obviously not *static* electricity. The *source* of said current is the accumulation of a large static charge, which eventually, according to the law of the transformation of quantitative accumulation into qualitative transformation, produces a high enough difference of potential that the insulating properties of air break down and the accumulated charge flows as a *dynamic* current. The source doesn't matter; the same current would kill in the same way regardless of source.

Comment: @AlexP quite irrelevant. The idea is to kill with a static *shock*. Lightning is a form of a static shock. Why you single out me and don't say the same on Zeiss Ikon's answer is beyond me though.